# Listing of all files in directory?

Tags: python, pathlib

Can anybody help me create a function which will create a list of all files under a certain directory by using `pathlib` library?

Here, I have a:

[image]

I have

- `c:\desktop\test\A\A.txt`
- `c:\desktop\test\B\B_1\B.txt`
- `c:\desktop\test\123.txt`

I expected to have a single list which would have the paths above, but my code returns a nested list.

Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path

def searching_all_files(directory: Path):   
    file_list = [] # A list for storing files existing in directories

    for x in directory.iterdir():
        if x.is_file():

           file_list.append(x)
        else:

           file_list.append(searching_all_files(directory/x))

    return file_list


p = Path('C:\\Users\\akrio\\Desktop\\Test')

print(searching_all_files(p))
```

Hope anybody could correct me.

Comment: use `extend` instead of `append` in the second case?

Answer (score 232):

Use [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to list all files and directories. And then filter it in a [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
p = Path(r'C:\Users\akrio\Desktop\Test').glob('**/*')
files = [x for x in p if x.is_file()]
```

### More from the `pathlib` module:

- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), part of the standard library.
- [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

Comment: what if I want to list all directories in a directory?

Comment: To list all directories simply replace "x.is_file()" with "x.is_dir()" as described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_dir)

Comment: `Path.glob(*)` still has a bug with not following symlinks: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77609 — if you need symlink support you, for example, could use a custom walk generator, fallback to the old `glob` module, etc

Answer (score 72):

With pathlib, it is as simple as the below comand.

```
path = Path('C:\\Users\\akrio\\Desktop\\Test')    
list(path.iterdir())
```

Comment: Need only list of files (not dirs)?  one liner: 
[f for f in Path(path_to_dir).iterdir() if f.is_file()]

Comment: Wrong. `iterdir` lists only the files in the directory but the OP has made it plain that he/she wants an explorer which will search down through the whole structure.

Answer (score 37):

```
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

def searching_all_files(directory):
    dirpath = Path(directory)
    assert dirpath.is_dir()
    file_list = []
    for x in dirpath.iterdir():
        if x.is_file():
            file_list.append(x)
        elif x.is_dir():
            file_list.extend(searching_all_files(x))
    return file_list

pprint(searching_all_files('.'))
```

Comment: assert is a statement, not a function, so I think you want `assert dirpath.is_dir()` with no parenthesis. In Python 2 and 3. Or simply `assert dirpath.exists()`

Comment: You should not use assert outside unit testing because assert is not working in some context.

Answer (score 19):

If you can assume that only file objects have a `.` in the name (i.e., .txt, .png, etc.) you can do a glob or recursive glob search...

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Search the directory
list(Path('testDir').glob('*.*'))

# Search directories and subdirectories, recursively
list(Path('testDir').rglob('*.*'))
```

But that's not always the case. Sometimes there are hidden directories like `.ipynb_checkpoints` and files that do not have extensions. In that case, use list comprehension or a filter to sort out the Path objects that are files.

```
# Search Single Directory
list(filter(lambda x: x.is_file(), Path('testDir').iterdir()))

# Search Directories Recursively
list(filter(lambda x: x.is_file(), Path('testDir').rglob('*')))
```

```
# Search Single Directory
[x for x in Path('testDir').iterdir() if x.is_file()]

# Search Directories Recursively
[x for x in Path('testDir').rglob('*') if x.is_file()]
```

Answer (score 18):

A similar, more functional-oriented solution to [@prasastoadi's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40216619/6045800) can be achieved by using the built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function of Python:

```
from pathlib import Path

my_path = Path(r'C:\Users\akrio\Desktop\Test')
list(filter(Path.is_file, my_path.glob('**/*')))
```

Answer (score 13):

If your files have the same suffix, like `.txt`, you can use `rglob` to list the main directory and all subdirectories, recursively.

```
paths = list(Path(INPUT_PATH).rglob('*.txt'))
```

If you need to apply any useful [Path function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to each path. For example, accessing the `name` property:

```
[k.name for k in Path(INPUT_PATH).rglob('*.txt')]
```

Where `INPUT_PATH` is the path to your main directory, and `Path` is imported from `pathlib`.

Answer (score 9):

### Define path to directory:

```py
from pathlib import Path
data_path = Path.home() / 'Desktop/My-Folder/'
```

### Get all paths (files and directories):

```py
paths = sorted(data_path.iterdir())
```

### Get file paths only:

```py
files = sorted(f for f in Path(data_path).iterdir() if f.is_file())
```

### Get paths with specific pattern (e.g. with .png extension):

```py
png_files = sorted(data_path.glob('*.png'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using pathlib2 is much easier,

```
from pathlib2 import Path

path = Path("/test/test/")
for x in path.iterdir():
    print (x)
```

Comment: pathlib2 is deprecated.

Comment: I didn't see how pathlib2 is related to this question. It seems that pathlib2 is only a backport of pathlib (to Python 2.x) and therefore `path.iterdir()` in pathlib2 cannot recursively walk the directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
def searching_all_files(directory: Path):   
    file_list = [] # A list for storing files existing in directories

    for x in directory.iterdir():
        if x.is_file():
            file_list.append(x)#here should be appended
        else:
            file_list.extend(searching_all_files(directory/x))# need to be extended

    return file_list
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pathlib

def get_all_files(dir_path_to_search):
    filename_list = []

    file_iterator = dir_path_to_search.iterdir()

    for entry in file_iterator:
            if entry.is_file():
                #print(entry.name)
                filename_list.append(entry.name)

    return filename_list
```

The function can we tested as -

```
dir_path_to_search= pathlib.Path("C:\\Users\\akrio\\Desktop\\Test")
print(get_all_files(dir_path_to_search))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
folder: Path = Path('/path/to/the/folder/')

files: list = [file.name for file in folder.iterdir()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator like this one with online filtering:

```py
for file in (_ for _ in directory.iterdir() if _.is_file()):
    ...
```