# How to delete all files in folder except CSV?

Tags: python, pyspark

I wrote a dataframe to a csv in Pyspark. And I got the output files in the directory as:

> ._SUCCESS.crc

> .part-00000-6cbfdcfd-afff-4ded-802c-6ccd67f3804a-c000.csv.crc

> part-00000-6cbfdcfd-afff-4ded-802c-6ccd67f3804a-c000.csv

How do I keep only the CSV file in the directory and delete rest of the files, using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
import os
directory = "/path/to/directory/with/files"
files_in_directory = os.listdir(directory)
filtered_files = [file for file in files_in_directory if not file.endswith(".csv")]
for file in filtered_files:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(directory, file)
    os.remove(path_to_file)
```

first, you list all files in directory. Then, you only keep in list those, which don't end with .csv. And then, you remove all files that are left.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the files in the directory, and then `os.remove` only those files that do not end with `.csv`.

```
import os
dir_path = "path/to/the/directory/containing/files"
dir_list = os.listdir(dir_path)
for item in dir_list:
    if not item.endswith(".csv"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_path, item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have fun with list comprehension for doing this:

```
import os

dir_path = 'output/'

[os.remove(os.path.join(dir_path, item)) for item in os.listdir(dir_path) if not item.endswith('.csv')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html) (Python >= 3.4) and the in-build type [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to substract all csv filenames from the list of all files. I would argument this is easy to read, fast to process and a good pythonic solution.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('/path/to/directory/with/files')
>>> # Get all file names
>>> # https://stackoverflow.com/a/65025567/4865723
>>> set_all_files = set(filter(Path.is_file, p.glob('**/*')))
>>> # Get all csv filenames (BUT ONLY with lower case suffix!)
>>> set_csv_files = set(filter(Path.is_file, p.glob('**/*.csv')))
>>> # Create a file list without csv files
>>> set_files_to_delete = set_all_files - set_csv_files
>>> # Iteratore on that list and delete the file
>>> for file_name in set_files_to_delete:
...     Path(file_name).unlink()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk('Test', topdown=true):
    for name in files:
        fp = os.path.join(root, name)
        if name.endswith(".csv"):
            pass
        else:
             os.remove(fp)
```

What the advandtage of `os.walk`?, it reads all the subdirectory in particular directory mentioned.