# How to get number of images folder

Tags: python

I have a folder having 7000+ images. I want to find the exact length of these images.

```
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/iuxray/images/images_normalized"
```

I use the following code for printing the length of total number of images in this folder.

```
print(f"Number of images: {len(path)}")
```

But it prints just 54 images like below

```
Number of images: 54
```

So I want to know where am I doing wrong. How to print the exact number of images

Comment: 54 is the number of characters in the path string you defined.  You probably want to look at the `os` package and the `listdir` function (that'll give you a list of file names in a directory).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of files in a directory using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632205/how-to-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were printing the length of the directory path which is a string, this should give the list of files and its length

```
import os
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/iuxray/images/images_normalized"
fileList=os.listdir(path)
print(len(fileList))
# for checking whether file is not a directory
print(len([fname for fname in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, fname))]))
```

Comment: This will include files & directories. This answer explains how to specifically get a list of files using `pathlib` and `is_file()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/40216619/13188999.

Comment: Includes sub-directories in the count. You could filter it out with a list comprehension and then take it's length. Also consider, while not in the question verification of the files to be images themselves.