# Python: zip all folders in directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

If I know the path of the directory, how can I zip **separately** all the folders in it? I tried something, but since I don't fully understand how the os module works, there's not much I can do.

```
import os, zipfile

directory_path = str(raw_input())
for folder in os.listdir(directory_path):
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(folder + '.zip', 'w')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path+'/'+folder):
        for file in files:
            zip_file.write(os.path.join(root, file),file)
    zip_file.close()
```

The problem is that it only zips one folder from the directory.

Example:

```
Directory
 |
 +-- folder1
 |  |  
 |  \-- file 1.1
 |
 +-- folder2
 |  |  
 |  \-- file 2.1
 |    
 +-- folder3
 |  |  
 |  +-- file 3.1
 |  \-- file 3.2
```

What I want to get is folder1.zip (contains file 1.1), folder2.zip (contains file 2.1) and folder2.zip (contains file 3.1 and file 3.2

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Do you have multiple folders inside the directory you are providing? Use `zip_file.write(os.path.join(root, file),file)` to prevent creating the extra directories.

Comment: @Mahesh I do have multiple folders. Thank you, it zips correctly now, but it still zips only one folder in the directory.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the input directory and the desired output?

Comment: @DanielePantaleone I've added an example, hope this is what you've meant.

Comment: Can you provide the definition for `r` regex?

Comment: @Lav Sorry, forgot to delete that.

Comment: @shomz Sorry, I still do not understand your problem. Can you elaborate what you mean by *zip separately*? Your example also seems to show the input, not the output. As output, I'd expect something like *zipfile1.zip contains folder1/file1, folder2/file2, zipfile2.zip contains folder2/file2, folder3/file3* etc.

Comment: @phihag I've added what you've asked for. :)

Comment: @shomz Thanks! I'm still a little bit puzzled, because your current code seems to do precisely what you want. For example, `folder1.zip` contains `file1.1` for me just fine.

Comment: @phihag Does the for loop go over every folder in the directory? Because I get folder1.zip, but not folder2.zip and folder3.zip

Comment: @shomz I do get `folder2.zip` as well as `folder3.zip` in my tests, and I see nothing wrong with the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are specifying a different `arcname` for every file in the zip archive (2nd parameter of the `write` method). Try the following (I also replaced some code like paths joining using `os.path` module instead of string concatenation):

```
import os
import zipfile

path = raw_input('Enter the directory: ')
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser(path)))
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('{0}.zip'.format(os.path.join(path, folder)), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(path, folder)):
        for filename in files:
            zipf.write(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, filename)), arcname=filename)
    zipf.close()
```

Comment: This zips each file separately as I wanted, but it contains every folder in the path, instead of just the files.

Comment: Could you please be more clear? Do you mean that `folder1.zip` contains the directory `folder1` with all the files in it, instead of just the files?

Comment: What I mean is that if the path is /Users/shomz/Documents/directory, then the folder1.zip contains a folder users and then in it shomz, then directory and _then_ the folder I need.

Comment: Ok, now I understood the problem :). I edited the answer. The problem was indeed in the arcname. For more info check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7007868/3477005